# Insert a figure on odd pages

Tags: graphics, conditionals, double-sided

I would like to insert a logo on each odd pages of my document (but the first) I know how to do it for each page but cannot figure out how to only do it on odd pages. So I have

```
\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
            \setlength{\@tempdimb}{0.24\paperwidth}%
            \setlength{\@tempdimc}{1.795\paperheight}%
            \setlength{\unitlength}{0.5pt}%
            \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25 \textwidth]{logo.eps}
            }%
}
\makeatother
```

I guess my issue is I do not really know how to put "if" conditions in that code! Could anyone help me on that?

Comment: The correct if statement here is `\ifodd\c@page ... \fi`. Put the `\if` part after 2nd line of your code and the `\fi` part before the closing `}`. Does it help? (I would try to test it but you have not provided [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so I don't even know which package you use.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct if statement here is `\ifodd\c@page ... \fi`. Put the `\if` part after 2nd line of your code and the `\fi` part before the closing `}`.